# Audio does not play in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app I reference to my audio file through JSON. As you can see from the code below.

```
const lines = [
  {
    id: 'dialogue1',
    parts: [
      {
        text: `как дела?`,
        audio: 'audio/audio1.mp3',
        prompt: '',
        speaker: 1,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        text: 'у меня все хорошо, а как ты?',
        audio: 'audio/аудио2.mp3',
        prompt: 'Say that: I am OK, how about you?',
        speaker: 2,
        id: 2,
        helpers: [
          {
            word_mother: "I'm all right",
            word_target: 'У меня все хорошо'
          },
          {
            word_mother: 'And you?',
            word_target: 'А как ты?'
          }
        ]
      }
}]
```

Audio files are kept in a public folder.

[image]

The issue is that when I go to a particular item in the app, my audio does not work. As you can see from the picture below, the play button is disabled. Could you help me please. I have tried some solutions but they don't work.

[image]

BubbleSpeechFrame.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
import Tooltip from './Tooltip';
import Button from './Button';

class BubbleSpeechFrame extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showText = this.showText.bind(this);
  }

  showText(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].childNodes[0].classList.toggle(
      'show'
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { lines } = this.props;
    const dialogueData =
      lines &&
      lines.parts.map(part => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {part.speaker === 1 ? (
              <div className="speaker-1">
                <div className="sound-cont">
                  <ReactAudioPlayer
                    src={part.audio}
                    autoPlay
                    controls
                    controlsList="nodownload"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="text-cont">
                  {<p className="text">{part.text}</p>}
                </div>
                {part.prompt && (
                  <div className="prompt-cont">
                    <p className="prompt">{part.prompt}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
                <div className="toggle-text">
                  <Button showText={this.showText} />
                </div>
                {part.helpers && <Tooltip tips={part.helpers} />}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="speaker-2">
                <div className="sound-cont">
                  <ReactAudioPlayer
                    src={part.audio}
                    autoPlay
                    controls
                    controlsList="nodownload"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="text-cont">
                  {<p className="text">{part.text}</p>}
                </div>
                {part.prompt && (
                  <div className="prompt-cont">
                    <p className="prompt">{part.prompt}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
                <div className="toggle-text ">
                  <Button showText={this.showText} />
                </div>
                {part.helpers && <Tooltip tips={part.helpers} />}
              </div>
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="centered">Bubble speech frame</h1>
        {dialogueData}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BubbleSpeechFrame;
```

Comment: can you show us the network tab in chrome devtools? I want to see that the sounds are being loaded properly and not lost in translation due to some utf8 formatting

Comment: How can I share it with you?

Comment: just do a screenshot and edit the question with the new screenshot

Comment: Link to the picture https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4RH2/3w62QBSy5

Comment: refresh the page with the network tab open and see if the audio files are being loaded into the app

Comment: They have loaded, with status code 206 - partial content

Comment: ok, can you show me the piece of code that connects the audio to the player / click button? show some logic that handles the audio files

Comment: I have update my question.

Comment: I have tried, it is the same. That is why I am so desperate to do it.

Comment: try chaning the ReactAudioPlayer src to something like this: `src={'./'+part.audio}`. different operation systems treat files and directories abit differently

Comment: With src={'./'+part.audio} audio does not loat at all, I have looked at the network tab.

Comment: also notice that in your json the first audio file name is in English while the file itself is named in Russian. try to name your files in English also for testing

Comment: Thanks I did not notice about first one, however, it does not work anyway.

Comment: try ti add ` src={require(part.audio)}` to include the whole audio file, make sure it includes the file and then try playing it

Comment: It does not work, maybe I need to do something related to path? Do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved my problem. In the `audio` field of the `lines` array, it is necessary to provide a path to an audio. For example, `audio: path.resolve('/audio/audio1.mp3')`. All audio files are stored in the audio folder, which is stored in the public folder.